# resolve all "changed-by them" or "deleted by the them" during rebase

Tags: git, rebase

I'm doing a rebase where I would like to always take the conflicting files as-is from the branch A.

on branch A

```
git rebase -X theirs branchQ
```

( According to [Is there a "theirs" version of "git merge -s ours"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173919/is-there-a-theirs-version-of-git-merge-s-ours) and [Choose Git merge strategy for specific files ("ours", "mine", "theirs")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16825849/choose-git-merge-strategy-for-specific-files-ours-mine-theirs/39141125) : "theirs" should mean "use the versions from A". In rebase the meaning of theirs and ours are reversed with respect to a merge )

But, I still get conflicts for files that were modified and deleted. I would like to go with the contents for A all the time.

```
git status

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)

        deleted by them: A/XB.cs
        deleted by them: A/YB.cs
        deleted by them: B/XD.cs
        deleted by them: B/YD.cs
```

and MANY more.

I can fix this by `git rm A/XB.cs` etc, **but how can I accept *all* these deletions (and all other changes from branch A)?** 
(It's a 28 stage rebase, so I'm looking for automation)

With respect to the common parent of branches A and branchQ, branchQ contains *only* line-ending normalizations, not new or deleted files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that `-X` arguments have no effect at all on what I call *high level* conflicts.  See ["-X theirs" option does not seem to work with certain Git conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40270434/1256452) and also [What are the reasons and cases that cause git merge conflicts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44359334/1256452)

I do not have a canned script that will do this for you, but experiment with:

```
git ls-files --stage
```

Note that files that were "deleted by them" will exist as entries in staging slots 1 and 2 but not in slot 3.  These are the names to pass to `git rm` to tell Git to remove the stage 1 and 2 entries.

For a description of how merge uses the four staging slots allowed for each file entry in the index, see [How do contents of git index evolve during a merge (and what's in the index after a failed merge)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21309490/1256452)

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean exactly by stages and slots?
I realized, that what and alternative approach would be to get `filter-branch` to call `git add --renormalize .` but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Ah, I need another link to where I describe how merge works within the index using the various staging slots...

Comment: Perhaps I was just not brave enough? Now trying `git filter-branch --tree-filter 'git add --renormalize .' parentID..HEAD`

Comment: Yikes, don't do that, it's a waste of time. A `--tree-filter` is meant to modify the tree *in place:* filter-branch extracts all the files to a temporary directory, you modify the files in place, and filter-branch constructs a new commit from whatever files and contents you have left behind. `add --renormalize` doesn't touch the work-tree at all!

Comment: You can, if you like, do something equivalent: use `--tree-filter` to run an editor / cleaner over all the extracted files. Note that $PWD during the tree filter points to some sub-directory deep within a temporary directory that `git filter-branch` has created, *not* to the usual work-tree; this is where Git is going to take the new files to make the new commit.

Comment: :-) Yes. But how do I emulate what `git add --renormalize .` does by doing something to the the working tree? I could start to parse and manipulate files myself but, easy to get wrong. Some context: I use autorclf on windows. The repo contains >100000 files with mixed line endings, and a mix of binary files with various names marked by .gitattributes. Perhap's it's easier to write a script that fetches the content of each commit in turn into an empty directory, adds with git add --renormalize and commits.
Or, perhaps I should go with your answer and check "git ls-files --stage".
Many thanks!

Comment: In general, unless you control *all* the clones of a repository, using filter-branch is a bad idea anyway. I'd suggest going about this differently, unless this is just your own repository or you're in a position to force everyone else to switch to your rewritten commits.

Comment: Yes, that's clear. This is about a not-yet shared branch. In any case I plan to  first/also do a single normalize commit shared to master at a coordinated time. Trying to save that work....
We started to move around directories in that branch, and did not realize that it triggered renormalization due to autocrlf...

Comment: Ah, OK, then it's safe enough. Still, there's that renormalize issue. There may be a way to adapt the trick I outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43464164/1256452).

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and found on Linux for filenames without whitespace I can use:

```
git status --short | grep "^UD"| cut -d " " -f 2|xargs git add
```

The status "UD" identifies files that are unmerged, deleted by them.